# getting Application error code 503 favicon angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, heroku, heroku-cli

This is the first time i am deploying my application in Heroku.

My Deployment got success but i got error as below.

[image]

when i run heroku logs --tail

I am getting this error

I tried maximum from online and stackoverlow still I am getting the same error

here is my package.json

```
                    {
                  "name": "ff-fabric",
                  "version": "1.0.1",
                  "description": "ImagEditor",
                  "license": "MIT",
                  "scripts": {
                    "ng": "ng",
                    "start": "ng serve --o",
                    "build": "ng build",
                    "dist": "ng build --prod --aot=false",
                    "test": "ng test",
                    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
                    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
                    "lint": "ng lint",
                    "e2e": "ng e2e"
                  },
                  "engines": {
                    "node": "14.15.4",
                    "npm": "7.6.0"
                  },
                  "author": "check",
                  "keywords": [
                    "kitchensink",
                    "canvas",
                    "angular",
                    "fabricjs",
                    "editor",
                    "images",
                    "fabric"
                  ],
                  "dependencies": {
                    "@angular/common": "^11.2.3",
                    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.3",
                    "@angular/core": "^11.2.3",
                    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.3",
                    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
                    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.3",
                    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.3",
                    "@angular/router": "^11.2.3",
                    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.0.2",
                    "@types/fabric": "^4.2.2",
                    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
                    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
                    "fabric": "^4.3.1",
                    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
                    "ng-lazyload-image": "^9.1.0",
                    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
                    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
                    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.3",
                    "ng2-pagination": "^2.0.2",
                    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
                    "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
                    "ngx-font-picker": "^11.0.1",
                    "nouislider": "^14.6.3",
                    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
                    "serve": "^11.3.2",
                    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
                    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
                  },
                  "devDependencies": {
                    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.2",
                    "@angular/cli": "11.2.2",
                    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.3",
                    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.4",
                    "@types/node": "~14.14.31",
                    "codelyzer": "~6.0.1",
                    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
                    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
                    "karma": "~6.1.1",
                    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
                    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
                    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
                    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
                    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
                    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
                    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
                    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
                    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
                  }
                }
```

[image]

Here is my SRC

[image]

Comment: By any chance you are hard setting the port to be used?

Comment: no there is no any configuration file

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid i have attached my sstructure screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Few configuration changes to your package.json should make it work.

1. Move the angular cli from devDependencies to dependencies. This is because by default, Heroku will only install the packages listed in the dependencies object and will ignore those in devDependencies. Since we want the application build step to take place on the server rather than on our local machine, ng commands on the server wont be accessible as its mentioned as a dev dependency by angular apps.

   ```
   "@angular/cli": "11.2.2",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.3"
   ```
2. Under script section of package.json

   ```
    "start": "node server.js"
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
   ```
3. Install express server by running the below command in terminal

   ```
   npm install express path --save
   ```
4. Create a 'server.js' file in the root of your application to serve the app from the 'dist' folder which is created.

   ```
     //Install express server
     const express = require('express');
     const path = require('path');
     const app = express();

     // Serve only the static files form the dist directory
     app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/<name-of-app>'));
     app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/<name-of-app>/index.html'));
     });

     // Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
     app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.M Glad it started giving you the direction. What's the remaining bit that need to be addressed?

Comment: I am getting some issues in the deployment similar like this 

Property 'selectedSize' is private and only accessible within class 'EditorComponent'.
110                   <select id="dimension-preset" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedSize"

Comment: Thats a Typescript error and not related to Heroku. Inside your class 'EditorComponent' you are setting the property as 'private selectedSize'. Hence wont be allowed to use in the template. Two options a) remove keyword 'private' from the property selectedSize b) If you don't want to expose 'selectedSize' directly in your template assign it to another property. Say userSelectedSize = selectedSize; and use userSelectedSize in the html template, [(ngModel)]="userSelectedSize"

Comment: sure i am trying that :)

Comment: Abdul after fixing all I am getting 404 error in heroku

Comment: no such file or directory, stat '/app/dist/imageEditor/index.html'

Comment: Whats the value of "outputPath" in your angular.json? Make sure it is "outputPath": "dist"

Answer (score 0):

I first removed all related to `favicon.ico` it means remove it from `index.html` and also from `angular.js`
Then follow those steps:

- Run: `npm install --save express path`
- Changes into `package.json`

```
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "start": "node server.js",
        "postinstall": "ng build --prod"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": "8.11.3",
        "npm": "6.1.0"
      },
```

- You can use `node --version` &
  `npm --version` to know the versions.
- Move @angular/cli, @angular/compiler-cli, typescripty "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8"__ __ * from `devDependencies` to `dependencias`.
- Create in root folder a `server.js` with this information:

```
    const path = require('path');
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    // Serve static files
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/MY_APP_NAME'));
    // Send all requests to index.html
    app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/MY_APP_NAME/index.html'));
    });
    // default Heroku port
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Replace MY_APP_NAME with your app name.

- In Heroku web page create an app and follow the Heroku deploy instructions.

References

- https://medium.com/@roliver_javier/como-desplegar-tu-aplicacion-de-angular-en-heroku-7b9941b6d39
- https://dev.to/gedgonz/haciendo-deploy-de-una-app-en-angular-a-heroku-16ji